# android.view.InflateException for some devices (mostly Android 4.4)

Tags: java, android

I see quite a number of crashes of my Android application with an android.view.InflateException. Unfortunately, it does not happen on my device or simulators and the error is telling me nothing. I am assuming it works for most of the devices, the error is mostly occuring in Android 4.x and rarely on 5.
Could any of you help me? That would be great!
It seems to happen when the users open up my preference activity. Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
  at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:315)
  at bloggersoft.sudokuoftheday.EinstellungenActivity$MyPreferenceFragment.onCreate(EinstellungenActivity.java:305)
  at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5467)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
```

Comment: Can you share the PreferenceFragment.java ?

Comment: the java or the xml file? honestly wouldnt know how the java helps .. there is a bunch of boring funtionality like possibilites for in app purchases ...the error occurs at     public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

Comment: What is the import for PreferenceFragment ?

Comment: sorry, the what? you mean the imports at the beginning of the java file?

Comment: Btw, I also can rebuild this error with an emulator with Android 4.4 running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to apologize. The code I posted was the full output from the developer console stacktrace and did not help me as well, upon testing it in the right emulator the error was shown: I forgot to set  a default value for a MultiSelectList preference. This fixed it.